# InfluxQL - select count per tag for multiple tags

Tags: influxdb, influxql

My data in `InfluxDB` for measurement with name `"measurement"` looks like this (`id` and `status` are `tags`, `value` is a `field`:

`{id:"string", status: "string", value: "long"}`

Every process that I want to describe can go through many states like this: `A`-> `B` -> `C` -> `A`, etc. Now I want to display the count of final state per `status` - I'm not interested in temporary states.

For example, for the set of data like below (assuming every new record has a newer `timestamp`):

`{id:"X", state:"A", value: 1}`
`{id: "X", state: "B", value: 2}`
`{id: "X", state: "C", value: 3}`
`{id: "X", state: "A", value: 1}`
`{id: "Y", state: "A", value: 1}`
`{id: "Y", state: "B", value: 2}`
`{id: "Y", state: "C", value: 3}`

I'd like to get a result like this:
`{state: "A", count: 1}`, `{state: "C", count: 1}`

Now, I'm able to achieve that, by explicitly specifying `state` like this:
`SELECT count("status") FROM (SELECT last("value"),"status" FROM "measurement" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "id") WHERE "status" =~ /^A$/`

However, I'd like to have a pre-defined variable with all possible statuses so that I do not need to repeat that query for every status. If I try something like this:

`SELECT count("status") FROM (SELECT last("value"),"status" FROM "measurement" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "id") WHERE "status" =~ /^$var_statuses$/ GROUP BY "status"` where `var_statuses` is a list of possible statuses, like: `["A","B","C"]`.

I'm ending up with the result as: `{state: "A", count: 2}`, `{state: "B", count: 2}, {state: "C", count: 2}` as there are those temporary statuses in between the beginning and the end.

Is there any way to transform my query so I can make it working?

Answer (score 0):

Via InfluxQL, you would probably be stuck with regex for now as there is no variable support or [IN operator](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/2157). You could try following regex queries:

```
SELECT count("status") FROM (
   SELECT last("value"),"status" 
   FROM "measurement" 
   WHERE $timeFilter 
   GROUP BY "id"
) 
WHERE "status" =~ /(A|B|C)/ 
GROUP BY "status"
```

If you are using InfluxDB v2, you could also try [Flux](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/) (which is a scripting language and provides more flexibility):

```
from(bucket:"your-bucket")
    |> range(start: $timeFilterStart, stop:  $timeFilterStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "measurement" and r._field == "value" and r.status = $var_statuses )
    |> group(columns: ["status"])
```

There you could use variables for substitution.

This is the [blog](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-influxdb-tech-tips-converting-influxql-queries-flux-queries/) talking about how to convert InfluxQL to Flux.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but your influx is basically what I've put into the question and said that it's not working. I can't use grouping by "status" like that or I will end up with temporary states in a result.